# Can I use Endpoints Frameworks with GAE if it supports only Python 2.7.x. It doesn't support Python 3.x?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am setting up a new API and Google Cloud Endpoints Frameworks looks like a good candidate to use with an AppEngine standard handler. The API handler is to accesses BigQuery in the backend - This seems to prefer newer cloud-api-client libraries.

Python 2.7 is deprecated at the start of 2020. I can't find any guidance on whether Google is going to update endpoints to support GAE on Python3.x or removed (replaced with some other product perhaps?)

App Engine now supports Python 3.x.

Should I be considering cloud endpoints framework for a new project?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, **Endpoints Frameworks** do not support **Python 3.x** yet.

A possible solution would be to use [Cloud Endpoints on **App Engine flexible**](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#top_of_page) environment.

Comment: @intotecho did you have any luck with Cloud Endpoints on the App Engine flexible environment?

Comment: I haven't found a good solution. App Engine Flexible would work with python3, but I didn't want the cost of running a compute engine instance 24/7 for a low volume api. I looked at Molten python framework which provides openapi functionality but not the API monitoring  and control features of endpoints. It would be good to know if endpoints for python3 standard env is even on the roadmap.

Comment: As of now I can't find any ETA yet. You could monitor this post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-cloud-endpoints/MnbLC95W1y4/nbmrUkVWBgAJ) or the Official Endpoints Release Notes [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/release-notes). As of the time being using Cloud Endpoints on GAE flex as suggested by @Denis T. is the way to go.