# Google cloud endpoints - support for Google Cloud endpoint framework 2.0 in python 3.7

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

We currently have an application that is written in python 2.7 in GAE. We use google cloud endpoint framework 2.0 described [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python).

the documentation clearly states that this is not supported on python 3.7. Google has announced end of support for python 2.7 in Jan 2020.

What are our options?

Can we expect Google to support Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0 on python 3.7? 
Or do we need to re-write our endpoint api using Open API?

We currently have existing mobile clients that use Google Cloud Endpoint Framework 2.0 libraries. Can GAE project (python 2.7, standard)  support both Google Cloud Endpoint Framework 2.0 and OpenAPI coexist together?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428630/can-i-use-endpoints-frameworks-with-gae-if-it-supports-only-python-2-7-x-it-doe

Comment: The SC question provides wrong answer. According to this https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks Google Cloud Endpoint Framework is not supported in Flex environment.

Comment: @Jacktileman - did you ever find a viable replacement for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks in GAE for Python 3? You mentioned that you had existing mobile clients that are using those libraries, which is my big reason for not wanting to go down the road of a full rewrite. I'm curious what path you ended up following here.

Answer (score 0):

> Google has announced end of support for python 2.7 in Jan 2020.

Google has not announced end of support for Python 2 -- that is the Python core development team: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

The App Engine long term support guide can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/long-term-support

Comment: These links don't answer the question that was asked. There is no mention of long term support (or lack of support) for Google endpoints framework 2.0 in python 3.7.

Comment: The endpoints framework is part of the 2.7 runtime. It will continue working as long as that runtime exists. It will not be supported by the 3.7 runtime -- if you need to use 3.7 instead, you will need to use an alternative framework.

Comment: Thanks Dustin. So can we assume that there are no plans to support Google Cloud endpoints framework 2.0 on python 3.7 by Google?

Comment: Hey Jack, there is a thread open on Google Groups where someone from Google posted an answer to this. It seems that at the current moment they are aware of it but there is no ETA, I assume that if in the future they want to disable the 2.7 long-term-support (after they keep it alive beyond 01/01/2020) they will provide a solution. 

Link to Google Groups post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-cloud-endpoints/MnbLC95W1y4/nbmrUkVWBgAJ